# C# Winform Image zoom with pixelate

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making simple image editor by C# winform.
I'm trouble with make zoom function. in other similar questions, many people simply suggest that 'change the size' such like..

Bitmap newImg = new Bitmap(oldImg, newWidth, newHeight);

But In this way, the picture become blured(is it caused by antialiasing? I don't know well...) I need pixelated zoom Image. Like any other image editor such as Photoshop or paint.net...

I tried also put pixelate function to make mosaic image. result was good but it was too slow!
please help me. How can I make pixelate zoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Image resizing in .Net with Antialiasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333589/image-resizing-in-net-with-antialiasing), this should get you started (I'm not sure but setting SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None means no anitaliasing).

Comment: Oh, I got answer.
e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
Just this one line make me happy :)
Thank you for link.